# Symfony extra controller for header

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible in Symfony2 to have a separate controller for only the header for example?

```
$this->render('MYBundle::page.html.twig', array('header' => $header));
```

Else I need to add the header value in every controller for every page.

Comment: you can do a sub-request to another controller, get the response, and include it where you want. https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit the Response globally using the Kernel Response event, as example, define a listener as:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // only do something when the requested format is "json"
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() != 'json') {
            return;
        }

        // only do something when the client accepts "text/html" as response format
        if (false === strpos($request->headers->get('Accept'), 'text/html')) {
            return;
        }

        // set the "Content-Type" header of the response
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
}
```

And register as follow:

<kbd>/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/services.xml</kbd>

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="acme.filter_response_listener" class="Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.response" method="onKernelResponse" />
        </service>        
    </services>
</container>
```

More info in this articles:

- [Symfony2: create a response filter and set extra response headers](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-create-a-response-filter-and-set-extra-response-headers/)
- [Symfony, edit the Response globally using the Kernel Response event](http://loige.co/symfony-edit-the-response-globally-using-the-kernel-response-event/)

Hope this help